# Deleting an aliased pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, unions, delete-operator

Doing this:

```
 union{
     int * integer;
     char * character;
 } u;
 u.integer = new int;
 delete u.character;

 u.integer = new int[5];
 delete [] u.character;
```

I assume this wouldn't work if any of these types have non trivial destructors, but is this ok?

Comment: Here's a closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2140319/57428

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't *work* in any case, if we assume *work* means having well-defined behavior rather than appearing to work (i.e. not crashing)

Comment: It really shouldn't be good enough; I could make an answer that says "It will always work and is perfectly well defined" and you would have no way of choosing which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is undefined behavior regardless of whether or not the item has a trivial destructor. If the destructor is trivial it may *appear* to "work" when in fact it's leaking memory, etc.

Comment: It might not even leak memory... it's just undefined :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say this is somewhere between implementation defined and undefined.

> 5.3.5/2: "In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the
>   operand of delete may be ... a pointer to a
>   non-array object created by a previous new-expression ... .

The value of the pointer does not change when used the way you did so, so this should work as expected, provided `sizeof(char*) == sizeof(int*)`.  The result of that particular comparison is implementation defined, and if the assumption is false then the behavior is undefined.

So it really really isn't particularly safe.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see this is a dangerous error. The two types might have completely different and incompatible ways of memory allocation and deallocation. This includes padding, garbage collection, bookkeeping, class-specific memory manipulation, etc. Just don't do it.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{

    public:

        void* operator new (size_t size)
        {
            cout << "A::operator new (size_t)" << endl;
            return malloc(size);
        }

        void* operator new [] (size_t size)
        {
            cout << "A::operator new [] (size_t)" << endl;
            return malloc(size);
        }

        void operator delete (void* ptr)
        {
            cout << "A::operator delete (void*)" << endl;
            free(ptr);
        }

        void operator delete [] (void* ptr)
        {
            cout << "A::operator delete [] (void*)" << endl;
            free(ptr);
        }

};

class B
{

    public:

        void* operator new (size_t size)
        {
            cout << "B::operator new (size_t) with some B-specific stuff" << endl;
            return malloc(size);
        }

        void* operator new [] (size_t size)
        {
            cout << "B::operator new [] (size_t) with some B-specific stuff" << endl;
            return malloc(size);
        }

        void operator delete (void* ptr)
        {
            cout << "B::operator delete (void*) with some B-specific stuff" << endl;
            free(ptr);
        }

        void operator delete [] (void* ptr)
        {
            cout << "B::operator delete [] (void*) with some B-specific stuff" << endl;
            free(ptr);
        }

};


int main (int, char**)
{

    union{
        A* a;
        B* b;
    } u;

    u.a = new A();
    delete u.b;

    u.a = new A[5];
    delete [] u.b;

}
```